# Trying to use bootstrap navbar brand and scrollTop()

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a single page website, using bootstrap and jQuery.  I've made it so, that every time when you click on one of the `<li>'s`, it loads the content, centers the page vertically using the scrollTop() function. 
But it doe not work with the navbar brand. I've tried everything and a half.

Semi relevant HTML

```
 <div class ="scrollUp">
 <!-- if buttonn active -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top topNavBar">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li id="myStory"><a href="#">My Story</a></li>
      <li id="webCoding"><a href="#">Web Coding</a></li>
      <li id="personalTraining"><a href="#">Personal Training</a></li>
      <li id="music"><a href="#">Music</a></li>
    </ul>
```

jquery:

```
$(".navbar-brand").on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
 eliezerButton();
$(".scrollUp").scrollTop();
```

Comment: You need to provide a working example of your that recreates the issue you're having. [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This is hard with the code that you've provided. But you're using topNavBar as a class in your navbar class is not a bootstrap class. Not sure if it's a class that you created, but that may be part of your problem.

Comment: I did create that class, my page has a nav bar on the bottom too.  I figured out this issue though.  Thank you anyway.